# SBT Resolver for plugin in local directory on Heroku

Tags: scala, heroku, sbt

I have an internal SBT plugin which sets up a lot of common aspects of my build. One of those is my setup to add my Artifactory credentials and resolvers. I typically publish the plugin locally so that my build can resolve it and then pull the remaining dependencies from my Artifactory repositories.

For deploying to Heroku, I planned to copy the published artifacts from my .ivy2 repo to a subfolder of the project. However, though I can get this to work locally using both Resolver.file and Resolver.url, I cannot get this to work once I push to Heroku. I even tried it as an unmanaged dependency but still unresolved in Heroku.

Does anyone know the magic spell for achieving this on Heroku?

I have attempted following in project/plugins.sbt:

```
Resolver.url.("local-plugins", url(s"file///${baseDirectory.value}/plugins"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

Resolver.file("local-plugins", file("plugins")(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "lib"
```

Comment: Did you also check the plugin files into Git?

Comment: You also might want to double check the value of `baseDirectory.value`. From the `project/` dir, it might not be what you expect because sbt has this concept of a project within a project.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend two different approaches:

- Use the [sbt-heroku plugin](https://github.com/heroku/sbt-heroku) instead of deploying with Git. You can use local dependencies this way.
- Deploy your plugin to [BinTray](http://bintray.com). It's fairly easy, free, and worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I revisited this again today and the following worked:

In plugins.sbt:

```
resolvers += Resolver.file("local-plugins", file("local-plugins"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

My project also contains a local-plugins/ directory in the working folder which holds the published artifacts.